# Json Parsing and assign to DTO using Jackson

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

Facing some issue while parsing JSON into DTO.

In Json Getting Response as below

```
{
    "errorMsg": null,
    "flag": "S",
    "message": "",
    "coi_Number": "1234567",
    "expiryDate": "7/12/2019 12:00:00 AM"
}
```

In DTO :

```
@JsonProperty("errorMsg")
    private Object errorMsg;

    @JsonProperty("flag")
    private String flag;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("coi_Number")
    private String coiNumber;

    @JsonProperty("expiryDate")
    private String expiryDate;

    @JsonProperty("errorMsg")
    public Object getErrorMsg() {
        return errorMsg;
    }

    @JsonProperty("errorMsg")
    public void setErrorMsg(Object errorMsg) {
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

    @JsonProperty("flag")
    public String getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    @JsonProperty("flag")
    public void setFlag(String flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("coi_Number")
    public String getCoiNumber() {
        return coiNumber;
    }

    @JsonProperty("coi_Number")
    public void setCoiNumber(String coiNumber) {
        this.coiNumber = coiNumber;
    }

    @JsonProperty("expiryDate")
    public String getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    @JsonProperty("expiryDate")
    public void setExpiryDate(String expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
```

Getting value as null. Please suggest what is the way to resolve it using Spring MVC.

In response getting value but after setting value in DTO getting `coiNumber` as `null`.

Comment: clearify your problem. `In response getting value but after setting value in DTO getting coiNumber as null.`

Comment: First of all, it is not required to put `@JsonProperty` on fields and getters, one of them should be enough, maybe this causes confusion to Jackson

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `private String coiNumber` to `coi_Number`

Answer (score 0):

In response, you are getting key as "coi_Number" but in the entity, you are using this.

Solution 1:

```
@JsonProperty("coi_Number")
private String coiNumber;
```

Try changing the above to

```
@JsonProperty("coi_Number")
private String coi_Number
```

Solution 2: 
If the above solution 1 doesn't work then try changing

`@JsonProperty("coi_Number")`

to

```
@JsonProperty("coi_number")
```